# Loading .xacro into .xacro does not have a visible effect

Tags: ros

I'm searching for an answer to why I can not see my second .xacro file that I'm including in my first one. - Here's my MWE:
I'm succefully loading a .xacro file and seeing it in Rviz by launching following launch file:

```
<launch>
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find my_package)/urdf/test.urdf.xacro" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" />
</launch>
```

My test.urdf.xacro file has following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="test">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find my_package)/urdf/glass.urdf.xacro" />

    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue1">
                <color rgba="0.28 0.52 0.93 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
     </link>

</robot>
```

My second .xacro file "glass.urdf.xacro" has following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="test2">

    <link name="base_link2">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 1" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue2">
                <color rgba="0.28 0.1 0.93 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
</robot>
```

The two files work seperatly but the `xacro:include` doesn't seem to be doing anything...Any ideas what I should do to use it succesfully?
How can I check what my resulting urdf file looks like?

Comment: Same problem here. Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. You need to use `xacro` to parse the `robot_description` in the launch file. Like this:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="xacro '$(find my_package)/urdf/test.urdf.xacro"' />
```

Otherwise, `xacro` isn't used to parse your `test.urdf.xacro` file and the included files are not processed.